# Java - Aromatic Numbers- inputting

Tags: java, arrays, input

An aromatic number is of the form AR, where each A is an Arabic digit, and each
R is a Roman numeral.

Each pair AR contributes a value described below, and by adding or
subtracting these values together we get the value of the entire aromatic number.
An Arabic digit A can be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 or 9. A Roman numeral R is one of the seven letters I, V, X, L, C, D, or M. Each Roman numeral has a base value:

---

This program is designed to take a AR value on the same line (inputted like  e.g. 3V), and multiply it. 3V would be 3 x 5 = 15. Since V is 5.

**My issue is that I cannot take what the user inputs and multiply an integer by a string. This makes it tedious. I tried converting the string into a int but the program gives me a *nullformatException*.**

Also A would be in the first cell [0] and R (the numeral) in cell [1]

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class AromaticNumerals
{
    public static int decode (String x)  // since input is direct the program doesnt require validation
    {
        if (x.equals ("I"))
            return 1;
        else if (x.equals ("V"))
            return 5;
        else if (x.equals ("X"))
            return 10;
        else if (x.equals ("L"))
            return 50;
        else if (x.equals ("C"))
            return 100;
        else if (x.equals ("D"))
            return 500;
        else
            return 1000;
    }



    public static void main (String str[])
        throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));

        int Output;

        int MAX = 20;
        String[] x = new String [MAX]; // by picking an array we can separate the A-R

        System.out.println ("Please input an aromatic number. (AR)");

        x [0] = (stdin.readLine ());


        int y = Integer.parseInt (x [0]);

        Output = ( y * decode (x [1]));


        System.out.println (Output);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    int MAX = 20;
    String[] x = new String [MAX]; // by picking an array we can separate the A-R
```

Incorrect.  All of your input is going into the first element of the array, `x[0]`.  You are confusing an array of strings with an array of characters.  The simplest solution is to eliminate the `String[]` and use a plain `String`, then extract the individual characters with `charAt()` or `substring()`.

Answer (score 1):

`stdin.readLine()` is going to grab all the characters from the console and store them in the string found at `x[0]`. You're then attempting to parse an integer from the full string, not just the first character, this is why your call to parseInt is failing. Instead, call parseInt on the first character via `parseInt(x[0].substring(0,1))` and pass the second character of the string to the decode method via `decode(x[0].substring(1,2))`. Also, if you don't need an array of strings, don't use one.

Answer (score 0):

Did you by chance come from a C background? Or any other languages where string is a pointer to the first element of an array of characters? Java works differently in that respect, a Java string is first class object so `x [0] = (stdin.readLine ());` reads the whole line into the first string so `int y = Integer.parseInt (x [0]);` will try to parse both A and R. Instead you want perhaps `x[0].charAt(0)` and x[0].charAt(1), also you don't need x to be an array.

Answer (score 0):

**Why you're getting errors:**

When you read the user input here

```
x [0] = (stdin.readLine ());
```

... you are reading *the whole aromatic number* e.g. 4V or whatever, and you are putting it in the first index of your array `x`. Then,

```
int y = Integer.parseInt (x [0]);
```

Here you try to parse *the first element of* `x` as an integer. But you didn't just put the integer part of the aromatic number there, you put the whole thing. You'll get a NumberFormatException there, because the Integer class can't parse the letter character you're passing it along with the number. Then,

```
Output = ( y * decode (x [1]));
```

... you try to pass *the second element* of `x` to the decode method, but there's nothing there, because you put the entire string in x[0]. That's your NullFormatException, because x[1] is null.

**To fix it:**

```
String line = stdin.readLine();
int y = Integer.parseInt(line.charAt(0));
int output = y * decode(line.charAt(1));
```

or whatever.